# Xamarin.Forms bunding in release

Tags: xamarin

Проблема которая сводит меня с ума) Люди помогите(

Есть простой Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Kitchener"
             x:Class="Kitchener.MainPage"
             xmlns:al="clr-namespace:AiForms.Layouts;assembly=AiForms.Layouts"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Kitchener.ViewModels;assembly=Kitchener"
             x:Name="_this">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:KitchenerMainPageVm />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Text="{Binding MessageText}"  
               TextColor="{Binding MessageTextColor}"
               IsVisible="{Binding MessageTextVisible}"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"  Grid.Row="1" FontSize="30" Margin="0,20,0,20" />

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Button Text="#" Command="{Binding ShowHideSettings}" WidthRequest="40"/>

            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding SettingIsVisible}" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <Entry Placeholder="Url Bullet Server"
                       FontSize="15"
                       Text="{Binding BaseUrl, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                       Completed="BaseUrl_OnCompleted"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Есть простой ViewModel:

```
 public class KitchenerMainPageVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            private string _baseUrl;

            public string BaseUrl
            {
                set
                {
                    _baseUrl = value;

                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BaseUrl"));

                    Settings.BaseUrlBulletHttpServer = _baseUrl;
                }
                get => _baseUrl;
            }

            private string _messageText = "Соединение...";

            public string MessageText
            {
                set
                {
                    _messageText = value;

                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MessageText)));
                }
                get
                {
                    return _messageText;
                }
            }

            private bool _messageTextVisible = false;

            public bool MessageTextVisible
            {
                set
                {
                    _messageTextVisible = value;

                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MessageTextVisible"));
                }
                get
                {
                    return _messageTextVisible;
                }
            }

            private Color _messageTextColor = Color.AliceBlue;

            public Color MessageTextColor
            {
                set
                {
                    _messageTextColor = value;

                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MessageTextColor"));
                }
                get
                {
                    return _messageTextColor;
                }

            }

            private bool _buttonStackVisible = true;

            public bool ButtonStackVisible
            {
                set
                {
                    _buttonStackVisible = value;

                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ButtonStackVisible"));
                }
                get
                {
                    return _buttonStackVisible;
                }
            }

            private bool _settingIsVisible;

            public bool SettingIsVisible
            {
                set
                {
                    _settingIsVisible = value;

                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SettingIsVisible"));
                }
                get
                {
                    return _settingIsVisible;
                }
            }


            public ICommand ShowHideSettings { protected set; get; }

            private void _showHideSettings()
            {
                SettingIsVisible = !SettingIsVisible;
            }


            public KitchenerMainPageVm()
            {
                BaseUrl = Settings.BaseUrlBulletHttpServer;

                ShowHideSettings = new Command(_showHideSettings);
            }
    }
```

В режиме debug-сборки все прекрасно работает, но как только все это дело собираю в режиме release-сборки часть моих привязок и команда отваливаются.

Во что я вижу при развертывании:

[0:] Binding: 'MessageTextVisible' property not found on 'Kitchener.ViewModels.KitchenerMainPageVm', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.IsVisible'
[0:] Binding: 'MessageTextColor' property not found on 'Kitchener.ViewModels.KitchenerMainPageVm', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.TextColor'
[0:] Binding: 'MessageText' property not found on 'Kitchener.ViewModels.KitchenerMainPageVm', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'

Работают привязки  SettingIsVisible,BaseUrl,ButtonStackVisible остальные не работают, что бы я не делал.... и команда то же не работает...

Я сто раз его пересобирал, пробовал запускать на реальном устройстве(Android 7.1), на эмуляторе, все одно....

Пользуюсь VisualStudio 2017 Параметры сборки библиотеки http://joxi.ru/823kkB8FJNGa82 Андроид-проекта: http://joxi.ru/5md77LnikRZ8xr
Версия SDK компилятора 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил, она оказалось в линковщике. Как он решил, что этот код нужно удалить не понимаю...
Есть два пути решения, отключить линковку(совсем или только для вашего проекта) http://joxi.ru/vAW339ei1vX6bA
Или воспользоваться [Android.Runtime.Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker